# Why do I always get errors when I run "npm install" in a project from github?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm-windows

I am trying to install a PEVN app from GitHub (just looking for repositories and download), but always when I try to run *npm install*, the installation process ends up with a huge bunch of errors. I have read that it might be necessary to use older versions of Node.js,then i have installed **nvm-windows** and started trying older versions. It generally doesn't work either. Maybe it's just because the packages on the git are non-working?

Here are the repositories that I failed to initialize via npm i:

https://github.com/Bonato12/stack-PEVN.git

https://github.com/yanekyuk/pevn.git

https://github.com/crmuhsin/pevn-survey-app.git

Comment: for example, this is error log in node 18.2.0:  https://jsfiddle.net/Netervey/ha0cjLzf/1/

Comment: Hi there, the error message indicates that you have no Visual Studio installed.
"npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio"